Redshift error: "permission denied on relation ___". But, I'm not using the table specified in the error message. What could cause this?
Summary
I'm using the Boto3 APIs (get_jobs & get_workflow) to  create an AWS Glue resource inventory for myself. The only manipulation performed includes basic data cleansing (flattening the JSON, removing and renaming columns) and that's it.
I've confirmed that it failed during the write to Redshift. What could cause this error when i'm not trying to access the table I don't have permissions to view?
Code Snippet

import boto3 
s = boto3.Session(region_name='us-gov-west-1')
glue = s.client('glue')

response = glue.list_workflows()['Workflows']
for w in response:
    response = glue.get_workflow(Name=w, IncludeGraph=True)['Workflow']
        
### DATA CLEANSING ###

conn_options = {'connectionName': 'my_redshift_connection_name'
            , 'redshiftTmpDir': 's3://bucket/temporary/'
            , 'useConnectionProperties': 'true'}

# Function used to write to Redshift
def func(dyf, conn:dict, schema:str, table:str, sql:str=None):
    final_table = f"{schema}.{table}"
    conn["dbtable"] = final_table
    
    if sql:
        conn["preactions"] = sql # SQL create statement
    else:
        conn["preactions"] = f"TRUNCATE TABLE {final_table};"
    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            frame= dyf, #Dynamic frame with data
            connection_type="redshift",
            connection_options = conn
        )

Error message:
An error occurred while calling o120.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: java.sql.SQLException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    ...
Caused by: com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException: ERROR: permission denied for relation *table_name_redacted*
    ...


Re-Running
Asking teammate for access (works, but doesn't solve the problem for automated scripts)
Reviewed my Redshift connection: It specifies a Redshift DB, but not tables.


Are you referencing a view that references the table in question?  Especially a late binding view.

No, I’m not referencing a view, although the relation object in the error messages was a view. I’ll have to check the type of view.

take a look at the EXPLAIN plan and you should be able to deduce how this table is factoring into your query

did you check if the IAM role has access to glue and redshift?
